# Gitlab-ci stage order ignored when rules includes changes

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-trigger

consider the following gitlab-ci.yaml, for a mono repo with multiple microfrontends

```yaml
stages:
 - build
 - deploy

build:app1:
  stage: build
  script: 
    - sleep 30
    - mkdir dist1
    - touch dist1/output1.html
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    changes:
       - app1/src/*
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist1
 

build:app2:
  stage: build
  script: 
    - sleep 30
    - mkdir dist2
    - touch dist2/output2.html
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    changes:
       - app2/src/*
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist2

deploy:all:
   stage: deploy
   script:
      - mkdir dist
      - cp dist1/* dist
      - cp dist2/* dist
      - deploy.sh ./dist
   artifacts:
     paths:
       - dist
```

when ran the order defined in stages is ignored and both the build and deploy jobs run simultaneously
causing a failure for the "deploy:all" job (since its still "building")

if i remove the condition for the `changes` the stage order is respected and build runs before deploy

how can i both  only act on changes and enforce the defined build order?

in the real monorepo there are 10's of micro frontends not just 2 ...

Comment: Is this the only and entire CI config in your repo, or do you have others? Is there an `include` somewhere? It may change your pipeline's behavior

Comment: @PierreB. no this is the only config

Comment: I wonder if the problem is happening because your rules mean Gitlab runs a merge request pipeline as well as a branch pipeline. Are you seeing two pipelines running? Then you might need to add a workflow section to resolve it.

Comment: @kmt that was it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your gitlab_ci.yml in Gitlab CI, it does not run the build and deploy jobs simultaneously. It runs a merge request pipeline (with the build jobs) and a branch pipeline (with the deploy job). Since the artifacts from the build jobs are created in the merge request pipeline, they aren't available to the branch pipeline, and so the deploy job fails.

It's difficult to say how to fix this without knowing what your intention is, but you need to run the build and deploy jobs in the same pipeline, so either have the deploy job run with

```
rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```

or have the build jobs run in a branch pipeline.

Additionally it's not clear to me how you're expecting the deploy job to always work, as if you only run the build jobs when there are changes sometimes not every build job will have an artifact and your deploy job will fail.

Comment: this seems like the most promising answer ... I will try it and accept it if it solves the issue....

it is a micro-frontend(single-SPA) monorepo ... so i would only build and deploy what needed to change ... It doesnt need to rebuild everything every time ...

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can try to use `needs` keyword in order to force relationships between jobs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs
You also nee to add `optional: true` since you have rules conditions in your build jobs.
You can add it in your `deploy:all` job like this:

```
deploy:all:
  needs:
    - job: build:app1
      optional: true
    - job: build:app2
      optional: true
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir dist
    - cp dist1/* dist
    - cp dist2/* dist
    - deploy.sh ./dist
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist
```

Comment: Would that wait for all the jobs to finish or would it fire as soon as one of them was done? I'll try it and see if it works. That'll be awesome if it does. I thought about this but I thought that it would fire as soon as one of the jobs finished instead of waiting for all of them... Solid suggestion though. I'll give it a try and see how it works out

Comment: it was worth a shot but using this technique still runs deploy simultaneously to both jobs ... not actually waiting for either

Answer (score 1):

Your deploy stage might need the condition for changes as well. Unless maybe you need the deploy:all stage to always run no matter if there is changes or not.

Also indicating that the deploy stage needs artifacts is always a good idea in your case because your deploy stage is using the artifacts anyways

```
needs:
  - job: build:app1
    artifacts: true
  - job: build:app2
    artifacts: true
```